# laravel - Delete method not working in laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8, delete-file

Hello I'm still a beginner at laravel, I got a problem on the delete method.

this my controller

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $home = Home::find($id);
        $home -> delete();
        return back();
    }
```

this my balde

```
<div class="col-6 sampah">
 <form action="{{ route('home.destroy', $home->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
    <a href="">
    <i class="bi bi-trash3-fill" style="width: 10px; height:10px;"></i>
    </a>
 </form>
</div>
```

this my route

```
Route::resource('home', 'App\Http\Controllers\TodosController')->middleware('auth');
```

When I press the delete button, why doesn't it work? Where is the problem? pls, help.

Comment: You need to change the `a href` to a button. Otherwise, it's just a GET link to the current page instead of submitting the form

Comment: maybe your model has softDelete check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first you need to get what you want to delete this is an example for you
it would be your controller:

///REPLACE Crud with your MODEL////

```
   public function destroy(Request $request,$id){
        $data = Crud::findOrFail($id);
        $data->delete();
        return redirect('YOUR_HOME_PAGE')->with('success', 'User is successfully deleted');
}
```

this is your blade:

```
<td>
                
                    <form action="{{ route('home.destroy', $row->id) }}" method="post">
                                                
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat show_confirm" data-toggle="tooltip" title='Delete'>Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to simplify things.

Instead of making the form in html, why not use a single anchor button to achieve the same.

```
<a class="#" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="{{ route('home.destroy', $row->id)}}">Delete</a>
```

href link is important. data-method is actually the type of route & you should use route type as delete as well.